# MacVim still uses the built-in Vim location when changing themes

Tags: vim, macvim, vim-plugin

I am new to Vim. I have been trying to change theme for MacVim 7.4, when I added the theme file PaperColor.vim to *~/Applications/MacVim7.4/colors* and restarted it, nothing changed.

But when I added the theme file `PaperColor.vim` to *~/.vim/colors*, MacVim changed its theme successfully.

Notice that I have aliased command vim to:

> ~/Applications/MacVim7.4/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim

Is this because I did not change the default path for MacVim? Thank you.

Comment: You would be better served asking this on http://vi.stackexchange.com/ but   romaini's answer still applies :-)  http://stackoverflow.com/a/31414638/71480

Answer (score 3):

```
~/.vim/
```

is the *only* location where you should put third party scripts.